# Pattern-Matching mixed with guards

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I wanted to define the function:

```
accumulate_list' :: Num a => [a] -> ( a -> a -> a ) -> a
accumulate_list' l f 
    | [] f = 0
    | (x:xs) f = f x (accumulate_list xs f)
```

but it doesn't compile, complaining that x, xs, x, xs, are Not in scope.

Trying to achieve the same result, I have defined this function

```
accumulate_list :: Num a => [a] -> ( a -> a -> a ) -> a
accumulate_list [] f = 0
accumulate_list (x:xs) f = f x $ accumulate_list xs f
```

it compiles well, and does like `sum` does on a list if the functgion passed in parameter is `(+)`. Yes, I finally found that indeed what I wanted to achieve was already existing in Prelude as the `sum` function.

However, I don't understand why the first version with mixed guards and pattern matching doesn't compile. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is because guards are basically a boolean expression. They have to evaluate to either `True` or `False`. Something like this should typecheck:

```
accumulate_list' :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> ( a -> a -> a ) -> a
accumulate_list' l f 
    | l == [] = 0
    | otherwise = undefined -- fill out undefined
```

It's also worth mentioning that since pattern guards were added to Haskell 2010, you're allowed to mix patterns and guards like so:

```
accumulate_list' :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> ( a -> a -> a ) -> a
accumulate_list' l f
    | []     <- l = 0          --pattern for the empty list case
    | 10 < 5      = 10         --arbitrary regular guard just because 
    | (x:xs) <- l = undefined  --pattern for the non-empty case
```

Answer (score 4):

Using what @Sibi's answer provided, I've completed it so as to provide entire working code example:

```
accumulate_list' :: (Eq a ,Num a) => [a] -> ( a -> a -> a ) -> a
accumulate_list' l f 
    | l == [] = 0
    | otherwise = f x $ accumulate_list xs f
                    where (x:xs) = l
```

Comment: you could write `accumul l f = case l of [] -> 0; (x:xs) | 5 < 10 -> ...; ...` which actually mixes pattern matching with guards.